# WPF VisualTransition is slow

Tags: c#, wpf

So I'm trying the example on the [Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/cc189093(v=vs.95)).
The problem I'm experiencing is that the transition is around 2-3 second. 
When I set `GeneratedDuration` I can make it only slower but not faster.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test_App" xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero">


<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#888888" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#555555" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MouseHover" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#AAAAAA" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#888888" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBorder" Color="#121212"/>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">


    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#444444"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#444444"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#BBBBBB"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border x:Name="RootElement">

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">

                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" >

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBrush" 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" 

                                                    To="Red" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBrush" 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                    To="Transparent"/>              
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Border.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="BorderBrush" Color="#999999"/>
                    </Border.Background>
                    <Border.BorderThickness>  1   </Border.BorderThickness>
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="1">
                        <ContentPresenter   HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"                                                
                                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"                                                 
                                            />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>

        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have no clue as to why it's so slow. As I've said, I tried using the `GeneratedDuration` that seemed that it might have been a bit faster, but no matter how fast I've put it would still take at least 2 seconds.

Comment: First, *which* transition is slow? You didn't specify that. Also, why don't you post your code where you tried using `GeneratedDuration`?

Comment: @Freggar 
Sorry I didn't specify the transition, but basically every transition. 
If I hover the mouse over the button the border would slowly turn red.
When I click on the button the border will slowly become transparent.

I didn't post the code with GeneratedDuration because if i understand it correctly, when you don't use it, it will go instantly.

Answer (score 2):

The `ColorAnimation` (and all other animations derived from `Timeline`) has a property called [Duration](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.duration?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Media_Animation_Timeline_Duration). Its default value is `Automatic`, which seems to result in a duration of about 2-3 seconds.

If you set the duration explicitly, you can get shorter or longer durations. In the following example, the duration is 0.5 seconds:

```
<VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" >
    <Storyboard>
        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBrush" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" 
                To="Red"
                Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
    <Storyboard>
        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBrush" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                To="Transparent"
                Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```